# Proving the set of all monotonic increasing sequences is closed in $\ell_2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following is a **homework** question, therefore tips on solutions are also kindly welcome.

Let $X=\ell_2$ be the set of all infinite sequences with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 < \infty$, with the metric:

$d(x_n,y_n)=\sqrt{(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-y_n)^2}$.

We define $A\subseteq X$, where $A$ is the set of all sequences such that for all $n$, $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ (monotone increasing).

Prove that $A$ is a closed set.

My remark:

Since $x_n \in \ell_2$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 < \infty $, therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^2 = 0$. So I think that the points in $A$ are all the sequences such that $x_n =0$ for all $n>N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

I.e $x_n \in A \iff x_n = 0 \;\;\forall n>N$

Does is help? Is it true?

Comment: What about the sequence $(-\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: As a tip for a solution: what is your/a common strategy to check whether a set is closed?

Comment: Either to check if the complement is an open set- which in this case seems, at least at a first glance rather difficult. The second option is to check if for every convergent sequence of elements in the set, the limit is also an element of the set.

Comment: Yes, the second approach should work. Note that here we have a sequence where each element is a sequence itself.

Comment: You can use that each of the linear functionals $x\mapsto x_{n+1}-x_n$ is continuous.

Comment: So a sequence $(x_n)_m$ of increasing sequences converges to some sequence $(y_n)$. You need to show that $(y_n)$ is increasing. But if $(x_n)_m$ converges to $(y_n)_m$ then for any fixed $N$ the sequence $(x_N)_m$ converges to $y_M$. So all that you need to show is that if $a_n\leq b_n$ then $\lim a_n\leq \lim b_n$ which is rather fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment from Jonas Lenz it is. Lear that any element in $A$ is a sequence with  non positive values that in increase to $0$. Suppose $(\boldsymbol{x}_m: m\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence in $A$ which converges in $\ell_2$. Then, for any positive integers $m,n$

$$ |\boldsymbol{x}_m(n)-\boldsymbol{x}(n)|\leq\|\boldsymbol{x}_m -\boldsymbol{x}\|_2$$
From this we see that
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\boldsymbol{x}_m(n)=\boldsymbol{x}(n)$$
Since
$$\boldsymbol{x}_m(n)\leq\boldsymbol{x}_m(n+1)\leq0$$

We can conclude that
$$\boldsymbol{x}(n)\leq \boldsymbol{x}(n+1)\leq0$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer based on a different approach..

It suffices to show that the complement $A^c$ of $A$ is open in $\ell_2$; to show this, for any $x\in A^c$, we need to find some radius $\epsilon>0$ such that, if $\|y-x\|_2<\epsilon$, then $y\in A^c$.

Indeed, if $x\in A^c$, then (by the definition of $A$) there exists some $n$ with $x_n>x_{n+1}$. Let $\epsilon=(x_n-x_{n+1})/2>0$. If $\|y-x\|_2<\epsilon$, then $|y_n-x_n|,|y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}|<\epsilon$. So
$$y_n-y_{n+1}>(x_n-\epsilon)-(x_{n+1}+\epsilon)=x_n-x_{n+1}-2\epsilon=0.$$
So, $y$ is not a monotonic increasing sequence, and $y\in A^c$, as desired.

Answer (score -1):

The approach you pointed out makes sense to me! It just needs a few extra steps.

Since $\lim_n x^2_n=0$, then $\lim_n|x_n|=0$. Since the sequence is monotone increasing, this implies that $\sup_n x_n=0$ (can you see why?). A similar reasoning applied to $-x_n$ shows that $\inf_n x_n=0$.

The only thing left now is to show that $\{0\}$ is a closed set, but perhaps you can provide the details of that :).

Comment: One cannot apply similar reasoning to $-x_n$, as the condition that a sequence is monotone increasing is not preserved under negation.